# How to pass input value to function in view.py

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

> **Objective:**

** To pass input value **itemnumbervalue** to **itemnumber()** in views.py

**> Error occured:**

method object is not subscribable line 17 in view.py

> Already applied techniques to correct the problem:

**case 1:** Tried **[]** and **()** both braces

```
if (request.POST.get['submitted']):
                c = request.POST['ENTER_ITEM_NUMBER']
```

I tried many options like **"remove get"**, and tried **braces() and []**

> **views.py:**

from .forms import InputForm

```
def home_view(request):
    context1 ={}
    context1['form'] = InputForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, "input.html", context1)

def itemnumber(request):
    if (request.POST.get['submitted']):
        c = request.POST['ENTER_ITEM_NUMBER']
        print("input valuegiven by user",c)*
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            itemnumbervalue =  c
            C=cursor.execute(f"EXEC ValidateBusinessrule '0000000000{itemnumbervalue}'")
            result_set = cursor.fetchall()
            result_set1= [' {} '.format(x) for x in result_set]
            context = {"row": result_set1}
            return render(request, "home.html", context)
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

> **forms.py**

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    regex = re.compile('^([1-9]{8})$', re.UNICODE)
    ENTER_ITEM_NUMBER= forms.RegexField(max_length=8, regex=regex,help_text=("Required 8 digits between {0-9}."))
```

> **home.html**

```
 <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <ul>
                <th>(column 1,column 2)</th>
            </ul>
            <tr>
            <ul >

                {% for row in row %}
                <td style= "text-align: center;">
                    {{  row }}
                </td>
            </ul>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

> **input.html**

```
    <body>
<form action = "{% url 'item'%}" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value=Submit" name="submitted">
</form>
</body>
```

> **problem details:**

To get input from user and give this input to *itemnumbervalue*  in itemnumber() in view.py. I already validated by putting itemnumbervalue='12345678' (without input value from user) is working fine and getting resultant table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `request.POST.get('submitted')` or `request.POST['submitted']`.

The difference is just that `.get` method returns `None` if key is not found in the dictionary, But with directly indexing key if the key is not found then it will throw `KeyError` exception.

To see what values you are getting in request.POST you can print it.

Also in `print("input valuegiven by user",c)*` remove the * at the end that's an invalid syntax.

P.S. I tried reproducing this issue and was successful in resolving by above specified method.